# How to get sys.stdout to print results into a tkinter GUI textbox

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox

I am fetching all the rows from MySQL database and trying to get them to print within the `textbox` and also using `sys.stdout` in my `table_frame`.
My printout isn't formatted for spacing properly yet. I'm trying to get the printout into the `textbox` first.

I tried to Highlight the code like StackOverflow says to, but it wouldn't highlight the text in the preview. Sorry if it is harder to read. Maybe it will fix itself when it post.

Thanks for any help.

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import mysql.connector

#  ======================MySQL Connection================================================================

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "<INSERT PASSWORD>",
    database = "testdb",
    )

# Create Cursor Instance
my_cursor = mydb.cursor()

table_frame = Frame(root, width=500, height=140, bg='yellow')
table_frame.pack(side=TOP)


textbox=Text(table_frame)
textbox.pack()
row = []

def inv_row_print():
    print("Item Code\tBrand\t\tUnits\t\tIn Stock\t\tUnit Cost")
    my_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM trialprojectdb.inventory")
    all_rows = my_cursor.fetchall()

    for row in all_rows:
        result = print("{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}\t\t{3}\t\t{4}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2],
                 row[3], row[4]))
        textbox.insert(0, result)
sys.stdout.write = inv_row_print() 


btn2 = Button(btm_frame, text='Show Table', command = lambda : inv_row_print())
btn2.place(x=200,y=90)


root.mainloop()
```

Here is the feedback I am getting.

```py
Item Code       Brand           Units           In Stock                Unit Cost
1               M&M Peanut              62              None            9.98
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Import_Test_Code2.py", line 124, in <module>
    sys.stdout.write = inv_row_print()
  File "Import_Test_Code2.py", line 123, in inv_row_print
    textbox.insert(0, result)
  File "C:\Users\darre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3269, in insert
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be ".!frame3.!text insert index chars ?tagList chars tagList ...?"
```

Comment: `print()` doesn't return string, it send string on monitor and always returns `None` so `resutl = print()` gives `result = None`

Comment: `print()` is function which use `sys.stdout.write` to send on screen. If you assign to sys.stdout.write function with `print()` then you will have loop - `print` will run `sys.stdout.write` which run `inv_row_print` which use `print` which use again `sys.stdout.write`, etc. Inside `inv_row_print` you should use `textbox.insert(0, result)`, not `print()`. And `result = "{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}\t\t{3}\t\t{4}".format(...)` without `print()`

Comment: @furas Thanks for the response. I updated the code and now it is giving me `_tkinter.TclError: bad text index "0"`.

Comment: @furas I got it figured out. Since it is a textbox I had to use `1.0` for the index instead of `0`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone else is having this problem I will post the solution that `@furas` helped me get.

> Original

```py
for row in all_rows:
        result = print("{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}\t\t{3}\t\t{4}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2],
                 row[3], row[4]))
        textbox.insert(0, result)
```

> New - removed `print()` from `result` and in `textbox.insert` changed the index from `0` to `1.0`. Also, deleted `sys.stdout.write = inv_row_print()`.

```py
for row in all_rows:
        result = "{0}\t\t{1}\t\t{2}\t\t{3}\t\t{4}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2], 
                  row[3], row[4])
        textbox.insert(1.0, result)
```